# MultiLayer LogisticRegression function with scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the `scikit-learn` package we found the function [`LogiticRegresion`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). However the parameters do not include the ability to create a multilayer neural network

```
LogisticRegression(penalty=’l2’, dual=False, tol=0.0001, C=1.0, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, class_weight=None, random_state=None, solver=’liblinear’, max_iter=100, multi_class=’ovr’, verbose=0, warm_start=False, n_jobs=1)
```

Is there any function or else, a workaround that allows you to add the hidden layers? I close function I found is [`MLPClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) which allows to use multilayer, but the output is the class for the classification.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic Regression and Neural Networks are not the same, you can learn a bit more about it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression. Also, despite its name LogisticRegression also does classification, the only difference is that it output the percentual chance of the example belonging to a class.

For Neural Networks in scikit-learn you should use the MLPClassifier for classification and MLPRegressor for regression: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html.

But, if you are looking for probability (like Logistic Regression), you can use predict.proba to make your neural network to output the probability.

Comment: Sorry for the vocabulary error, I want that percentual chance as in the Logistic Regression (which could be the last layer of a neural network). I would like to do it that way, with the minimization of the function described as in [page 18 - log likelihood](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf), but I don't see how add layers to play around with the input information. If I use `MLPRegressor` I'm interested in using the log likehood as in the logistic regression and not the squared error.

Comment: MLPRegressor does regression which is different from what LogisticRegression does (classification). Thats a common mistake, because those names are horrible. You should use MLPClassifier with predict_proba

Comment: You can see it in this page: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html . Down below in methods, there is a probability method too, called predict_proba

Comment: Also, as others pointed, I think Tensorflow with Keras are very nice. I'm still starting to study it

Comment: The only thing that I fear is the part is that the Classification function uses [Cross Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) as a loss function, which is not exactly the same as the one for logistic regression. I can give a look. And yeah, I'll probably I'll end up using tensorflow.

Comment: Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic Regression is not for performing regression despite its name.

Logistic Regression are often not thought of as neural networks    (especially by statisticians in the statistic community) but they [can be interpreted as single layer neural    networks](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/logisticregr-neuralnet.html).

You are probably looking for the    [MLPRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) class.

Comment: Is there a way to add logistic as final layer and relu for the others? The thing is that MLPRegressor uses squared-loss (y-y_hat)**2. And I would like to use the same equation for logistic regression as final layer (I could do it with tensorflow, but it would take more time to program the code).

Comment: More control over the activation function in the individual layers is not built in with sklearn. For that check out [Keras](https://keras.io/), which gives you more flexibility, but is on a high abstraction level and has also [sklearn wrappers](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) if you have a workflow in their API.

Answer (score 0):

[LogiticRegresion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) class from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) package suppose to work only as LogisticRegression (1-layer feedforward neural net with Logistic (a.k.a. Soft step) activation function).

There are [Neural Network](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html) models in Scikit-learn, but I would suggest using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), [Theano](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/), and [Keras](https://keras.io/). 
The last one is the best choice for Beginners.